# get Image from ImageView and convert it to Bitmap of system.Drawing

Tags: c#, xamarin

I want to convert Image in ImageView to bitmap Of System.Drawing to use in code 
or function It accept Bitmap of system.Drawing   not bitmap of Android.Graphics.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. I recommend you read take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the help section about creating a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54704519/edit) your question

Comment: System.Drawing is a Win32 class, it is not available on Android.  There are a few stub classes provided for compatibility, but otherwise it's not there.  It would be much more helpful if you explained what you were actually trying to accomplish so we could suggest an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use the Source of ImageView as like the Bitmap

Suppose:

Source of ImageView is filepath1, where the filepath1 is a file path string standing for a jpg file.

Then you can try the following code:

```
if (file != null)
        {
            byte[] imageBytes;
            var FileImage = new Image();

            string base64;
            using (var fs = new FileStream(file.FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                var buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
                fs.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fs.Length);
                base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
            }

            imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64); 
            File.WriteAllBytes(filename, imageBytes);
            var bitmap = new Image { Source = filename};

            imgViewer2.Source = bitmap.Source;
```